# How to plot multiple layers with Geoframes in python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, geopandas

Context: I've two data frames that i read with pandas from .csv files, one of them (dfevents) has a latitude and longitude fields on it, the other dataframe (dfplacedetails) has multiple points that creates a polygon. I'm usign "intersets" properties to verify when the first data frame cross with the polygon of the other one. That actually works fine, but when I'm triying to plot both of the layers is just not posibble, they plot separete

My code is as follow:

```
# Libraries
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gp
import pandas as pd

# Creating data frames

dfevents = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\alan_\Desktop\TAT\Inputs\Get Events\Get_Events.csv')
print(dfevents)
dfplacedetails = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\alan_\Desktop\TAT\Inputs\Get Place Details\Get_Place_Details.csv')
print(dfplacedetails)

# Make them proper Geometrys

dfevents['point'] = gp.GeoSeries.from_xy(dfevents.longitude, dfevents.latitude)
dfplacedetails['polygon'] = gp.GeoSeries.from_wkt('POLYGON' + dfplacedetails.polygon)

# Make them GeoDataFrames

dfevents = gp.GeoDataFrame(dfevents, geometry='point')
dfplacedetails = gp.GeoDataFrame(dfplacedetails, geometry='polygon')

# Output (It works fine)

dfout = dfevents.intersects(dfplacedetails)
print(dfout)

# Plot

fig, ax =plt.subplots(figsize =(20,10))
dfplacedetails.plot(ax=ax, color='blue')
dfevents.plot(ax=ax, color='red',markersize=10)
ax.set_axis_on()
```

The result that i got when I plot as I described up in my code is as follow:

[image]

But when I plot separate both of the layers plot fine:

[image]

Is there any way to plot both of them in the same image?

Thanks for you help!
By the way i'm using Visual Studio Code

Comment: Did you notice the scale are not the same? The green object seems to be very small. In your combined plot, try to zoom around 0.

Comment: It actually looks like it’s at (42, -72). And yeah the shape is tiny. I think your plot is fine but the shape is just not visible on that scale